# Paste only first line into Javascript Prompt but copy all lines

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a Javascript call logger form. A user fills out a form with information about their call and hits "copy" which will copy a div called "copyNote". This note will have several lines of information, however the first line of the note is always the subject. I am wanting a user to be able to paste the **first line** of the text into a prompt (as the subject) and then paste the entire (several lines) note into a form for logging purposes (supplied by the company), without having to copy just the subject, then go back and copy the entire note.

Can this be done just by using some type of breaking character to signal the prompt box to not paste anything else?

Using `br` tags or `\n` does nothing but put a space into the prompt box.

```js
function copyToClip(str) {
  function listener(e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", str);
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", str);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
};

function CopyToClipboard(element) {
  var block_level_elements = ['P', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'OL', 'UL', 'DIV', 'FORM', 'HR', 'TABLE'];
  
  var newelment = document.createElement("div");
  newelment.innerHTML = document.getElementById(element).innerHTML;
  newelment.style.opacity = 0;
  document.body.appendChild(newelment);
  
  var descendents = newelment.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0; i < descendents.length; ++i) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(descendents[i]);
    var dis = style.getPropertyValue('display');
    var tagname = descendents[i].tagName;

    if (dis.includes("inline") && block_level_elements.includes(tagname)) {
      var defultcss = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(descendents[i], "").cssText;
      descendents[i].outerHTML = descendents[i].outerHTML.replace(new RegExp(tagname, "ig"), "span"); 
      // todo: need to change RegExp to tag name only not inner text 
      descendents[i].style.cssText = defultcss;
    }
  }
  
  var doc = document;
  var range, selection;

  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    range = doc.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(newelment);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = doc.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(newelment);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
  document.execCommand('copy');
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

  document.body.removeChild(newelment);
  document.getElementById("copybtn").innerHTML = "Copied";
}
```

```css
.green {
  display: inline;
  color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<button id='copybtn' onclick="CopyToClipboard('foo')">
  Copy the stuff
  </button>

<div id='foo'>
  This would be the subject<br><br>
  <b> test </b> me <i> also </i>
  <div class="green" style="color: green;">Hello world</div> ,
  <h3 class="green" style="color: green;">header3</h3> You can use setData to put TWO COPIES into the same clipboard, one that is plain and one that is rich. That way your users can paste into either a
  <ul>
    <li>plain text editor</li>
    <li>or into a rich text editor</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/shane8johnson/pen/KKgaZvG

Comment: Please include pertinent code **in the question**. Fiddles and other links should be supplementary only.

Comment: @Mitya Updated to include code. Could you please remove the negative rating :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to paste 2 different string from same clipboard? Also, can you write javascript code where user pastes this from clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split to break the sentence.

[Read More about Split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```js
function copyText(){
    var node = document.getElementById('note')
    var htmlContent = node.innerHTML

    var note = htmlContent.split('.')

    var noteone = note[0]
    var notetwo = note[1]
    
    document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = noteone;
    document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = notetwo;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="note">My name is Jhon. I am 25 Years old, living in india.</div>

<button onclick="copyText()">Copy</button>
<br>
<label>copied text 1:</label>
<p id="text1"></p>

<label>copied text 2:</label>
<p id="text2"></p>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still require the user to copy the first note, then come back and copy the second note?

Comment: First copy all, use this code just before pasting, apply this code on copied text.

Comment: I'm still confused on how I would implement this. Would you happen to have a Jsfiddle or a sandbox of this working?

Comment: I have updated the snippet, look at that.